# Differentiability of $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

> Determine whether the function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as:
>   $$\begin{cases}\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^6} \qquad (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ 0 \quad \ \ \ \qquad (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}$$
>   is differentiable.

That's how I proceded.
Clearly $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ simply by seeing that the partial derivatives are continuous in this set. The only problem is in the origin.
Let's show that the function is differentiable in $(0,0)$ by applying the definition: we want that
$$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-<\nabla(f)(0,0),(h,k)>}{\sqrt{(h^2+k^2)}}=0$$
As we have $f(0,0)=0$ we have that $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=0$ and so the scalar product cancels out.
We now have to compute:

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{hk^3}{(h^2+k^6)\sqrt{(h^2+k^2)}}$$

By using polar coordinates we have:

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\left|\frac{hk^3}{(h^2+k^6)\sqrt{(h^2+k^2)}} \right|\leq \lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\left|\frac{hk^3}{h^2\sqrt{(h^2+k^2)}} \right|=\lim_{\rho \to 0} \left| \frac{\rho\cos\theta\rho^3\sin^3\theta}{\rho^3\cos^2\theta}\right|=\lim_{\rho \to 0}\left|\frac{\rho\sin^3\theta}{\cos\theta} \right|=0$$
so the function is differentiable in $(0,0)$ and so in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Is my procedure correct? Is there any faster way or smart observation I can do to work this out better? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The procedure is not entirely correct because of your first inequality; by ignoring the $k^6$ term, you've created an issue in the denominator regarding division by zeros. In fact, the function isn't even continuous at the origin.

Comment: That's exactly where my mind got stuck. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure is not entirely correct because of your first inequality; by ignoring the $k^6$ term, you've created an issue in the denominator regarding division by zeros. In fact, the function isn't even continuous at the origin; consider the path $t \mapsto (t^3, t)$ in the plane, and let's evaluate the limit as $t \to 0$.

Then, for $t \neq 0$,
\begin{align}
f(t^3, t) &= \dfrac{t^6}{2t^6} = \dfrac{1}{2},
\end{align}
so the limit as $t \to 0$ is also $\dfrac{1}{2}$. But clearly, if you take the limit along the path $t \mapsto (t,0)$ (i.e along the $x$-axis), you find the limit is $0$. Getting two different answers along different paths means the function isn't continuous.

---

I see several solutions regarding limits, where they go to polar coordinates to "solve" the problem. This is very dangerous, because it very often leads to subtle errors. In particular, you're assuming that $\theta$ is fixed, and that you're sending $\rho \to 0$. In other words, you're only evaluating the limit along a straight line! This is definitely not what the limit definition requires. You have the be able to approach the origin in any possible manner, and still obtain the same limit.

Comment: Clear, you made me understand a lot with this answer. +1, question answered.

Comment: By the way, supposed the function continuous, how can I execute the last limit without doing damages by going in polar coordinates?

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci also, I should mention that there are SOME instances where the method of going to polar coordinates is justified. But really, if you take a look at most "solutions" which use this method, there's some gap in the reasoning. IMO, the amount of effort required to properly justify the polar coordinate method is much more than just trying to do it directly in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: My advice is that (atleast if you're still learning the basics) in order to not give an erroneous proof, don't use polar coordinates. It may seem like a "simple" and good idea, but it isnt. For your second comment, well, this function isn't continuous, so I'm not sure what else there is to say about it. But, let's consider for example a different function like $f(x,y) = xy$. This will of course be continuous, and even $C^{\infty}$. But let's for the sake of discussion, prove directly that it is differentiable at the origin. Here, the partial derivatives vanish at the origin

Comment: Completely satisfied. Thanks again a lot.

Comment: So, essentially, we have to prove that $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$ exists and equals $0$. In this case, notice the simple inequality: $\left| \dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \right| = \dfrac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \cdot |y| \leq 1 \cdot |y|$. Therefore, as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, the RHS goes to $0$, hence the limit of LHS exists and equals $0$. This is one of the most useful (atleast for me) inequalities for this type of functions, where you have a quotient of "homogeneous polynomials".

Answer (score 1):

The function is not differentiable at $(0,0),$ because is not continuous. To prove it, consider:

- $\lim\limits_{y\to0}f(ay^3,y)=\frac{a}{a+1}$

Heine definition says that the limit does not exist (and is not equal to $0$).